# Base64-like string conversion, to smaller character set

Tags: c#, string, encoding

I have a series of encrypted strings that I use as ids in a C#/ASP.Net web application. I need to use these in the `id` attribute, however, the string contain illegal characters (valid characters are only ´[A-Za-z0-9-_:.]`). I need a **two-way** conversion that maps my encrypted strings to this small set. Something like Base64, but smaller.

What are my alternatives? Are there standard algorithms for this, or is it odd enough I have to invent it myself?

**Solution:**
In case someone needs this, here's what I ended up doing. Replace non-valid characters, and remove the padding = char. Then undo this to revert.

```
    private static string MakeReferenceJavascriptCompatible(string reference)
    {
        return reference.Replace("+", "_")
                        .Replace("/", "-")
                        .Replace("=", "");
    }
    private static string UndoMakeReferenceJavascriptCompatible(string reference)
    {
        int padding = 4 - (reference.Length % 4);
        return reference.Replace("-", "/")
                        .Replace("_", "+")
                        .PadRight(reference.Length + padding, '=');
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've got A-Z (26), a-z (26), 0-9 (10) and '_', ':' and '.' (3) then you've got 65 characters available, just like Base64. (It needs 65 rather than 64 due to using = as padding at the end.) It wasn't clear to me whether you *also* were including `-`, which would give you 66... positively *rich* in characters available :)

It sounds like you just need to convert the "normal" form to your slightly different alphabet. You could do this either by finding a flexible base64 implementation which lets you specify the values to use, or by just calling `string.Replace`:

```
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(input)
                    .Replace('+', '_')
                    .Replace('/', ':')
                    .Replace('=', '.');
```

Reverse the replacements to get back from your "modified" base64 to "normal" base64 and it'll be valid for `Convert.FromBase64String`.

Comment: I'm surprised I did not realize that I should count the available characters... But sadly it turns out that jQuery does not like : and . in ids, so there are not enough of them anyway. Good idea, though!

Comment: Around 1 AM I ended up doing this anyway, with "-", "_" and "---" as replacement strings. Probably going to end up biting me one day, though...

Comment: That doesn't sound great, no. You could probably get away with removing the padding, and just putting it back later on based on the length of the string - that way you only need 64 characters instead of 65. Does that help?

Comment: That does sound like a better idea. If I understand the algorithm, `=` is _only_ used for padding, and fills out the string so `length % 4 == 0`?

Answer (score 2):

"Smaller"? In the question you're stating that there are 66 valid characters:

- [A-Z]  : 26
- [a-z]  : 26
- [0-9]  : 10
- [-_:.] :  4

Give Base64 a chance, maybe replacing the "illegal characters" (+, /, =) by some other chars.

Answer (score 1):

You already  have 65 valid characters to use. So you can use base64 encoding with `String.Replace`. But if you want to use a case insensitive encoding (for example to use for a filename in windows) You can use [base36](http://www.stum.de/2008/10/20/base36-encoderdecoder-in-c/) encoding

Comment: As I note that there is a problem with base64 in a comment to Jon Skeet, Base36 is an interesting alternative. Thanks for the link, I'll check that out!

Comment: @carlpett If you are interested in Base64 encoding there are many other implementations of it such as [this one](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/lucene.net/branches/Lucene.Net_2_9_4g/src/core/Support/Number.cs?view=co) used in Lucene.Net

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in System.Web.HttpServerUtility to do this.

To convert a value to the encoded value (safe for Url and JavaScript use):

```
string result = value;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
{
  var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
  result = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(bytes);
}
return result;
```

To convert the encoded value back to the original value:

```
// If a non-base64 string is passed as value, the result will
// be same as the passed value
string result = value;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
{
  var bytes = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(value);
  if (bytes != null) {
    result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
  }
}
return result;
```